# Showing data in Laravel Chatter Package is showing Undefined Variable Error

Tags: php, laravel, package, laravel-5.6

I am working on adding a comment like stackoverflow using chatter discussion package by devdojo so here is the problem I am writing code to show comments but an undefined variable error is coming up.
[Error Page ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLvST.png)

```
public function show(Chatterreply $chatterreply ,$id)
{
    $chatterreplies = Chatterreply::where('chatter_post_id',$id)->get();

    return view('chatter::discussion', compact('chatterreplies'));
    echo "<pre>"; print_r('$chatterreplies'); die;
}
```

In Web.php route is

```
 /*
 * Post routes.
 */
Route::group([
    'as'     => 'posts.',
    'prefix' => $route('post', 'posts'),
], function () use ($middleware, $authMiddleware) {

    // All posts view.
    Route::get('/', [
        'as'         => 'index',
        'uses'       => 'ChatterPostController@index',
        'middleware' => $middleware('post.index'),
    ]);

    // Create post view.
    Route::get('create', [
        'as'         => 'create',
        'uses'       => 'ChatterPostController@create',
        'middleware' => $authMiddleware('post.create'),
    ]);

    // Store post action.
    Route::post('/', [
        'as'         => 'store',
        'uses'       => 'ChatterPostController@store',
        'middleware' => $authMiddleware('post.store'),
    ]);
    //Adding Comments
    Route::post('/reply/{id}', [
        'as'         => 'store',
        'uses'       => 'ChatterreplyController@store',
        'middleware' => $authMiddleware('post.reply.store'),
    ]);
    //showing Comment
    Route::get('/reply/{id}', [
        'as'         => 'show',
        'uses'       => 'ChatterreplyController@show',
        'middleware' => $middleware('post.show'),
    ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I would suggest putting your debugging statements (...print_r...) before the return statement in your controller action, this way :

```
public function show(Chatterreply $chatterreply ,$id)
{
  $chatterreplies = Chatterreply::where('chatter_post_id',$id)->get();

  echo "<pre>"; print_r('$chatterreplies'); die();

  // or use the laravel helper 
  dd($chatterreplies)

  return view('chatter::discussion', compact('chatterreplies'));

}
```

You should see the content of the $chatterreplies variable.

If this is ok, check your controller name in web.php because it seems that it should be ChatterReplyController@show instead of Chatter**reply**Controller@show (is the R letter in Chatter**reply**Controller@show capital or not ? ) if you're following the camelCase convention as in ChatterPostController@store for instance.

Comment: i did that changes still it is saying undefined variable.

Comment: what I did is I created a model and controller and I wanted to add a new module in the chatter package which I installed on my project to do so I moved the controller and model in the vender/devdojo folder where the other files were placed.